# How do I embed arbitrary unicode without messing up the rest of the line?

Tags: unicode, internationalization, right-to-left, left-to-right

So we have `header|sequence|string1|string2|directive` where string1 and string2 are arbitrary Unicode junk. Assuming the input can be really trashy Unicode (I'm expecting for it to contain things like right-to-left text, unbalanced Unicode direction control characters, etc) but not actually malicious, how can I get these strings to display in order?

The final website target is HTML but we believe it's best to process as string as far as possible. Blindly jamming a force-LTR before each `|` is not remotely acceptable as this tends to carry into the text past the `|` and cause RTL to render as LTR.

First step: replace control codes with [control pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures)

Second step: fix RTL nonsense ??

I have to admit I was expecting the [RTL stack](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Levels_and_Directions) to be simpler than it was. I cannot simply run the algorithm because there's no way to know the RTL-LTR-ness of a private use character.

Comment: Is splitting on `|` and then making table cells out of the parts acceptable? This sidesteps all the problems you anticipate.

Comment: @daxim: not tables but we're currently messing with fancy divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with this kludgy method. It works. (Note that in the production code these inline styles turn into a class reference.)

```
<PRE><DIV DIR=LTR STYLE="display:inline-block;">|</DIV><DIV STYLE="display:inline-block;">something1</DIV><DIV DIR=LTR STYLE="display:inline-block;">|</DIV><DIV STYLE="display:inline-block;">something2</DIV><DIV DIR=LTR STYLE="display:inline-block;">|</DIV></PRE>
```